# Редактирование пользователей из админки

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Есть админка в которой нужно реализовать возможность редактрировать пользователей, представленных в формате: `[{id:1, name: 'name'},{...},...]`. Формат payload post-запроса: `{id:2, name: 'name2'}`. 
Сам список пользователей в react-table. Саги и редюсеры написаны, нужно придумать как обновлять имя по id.